# Flexible prediction with neural network or other method

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, data-imputation

I want to use neural network for my first time, but I need to check if it fits for my case.

So, my idea is to teach a model on data like `Y = f(X1, X2...XN)` and then to be able to predict both options:

1) predict `Y-value` on the full input `(X1, X2...XN)`, where I defined X-values

2) predict most probable `Y-value` on the partial X-input (let's say I know X2, X3, but I dont know X1 and I want my model to set the most probable X1-value).

Could you advise something to start? Is it possible with neural networks to predict both complete input as well as partial input ?

**edition**

My problem №2 could be similar to imputation, but I am not fully agree.

As I have seen, it something like replacing missing values with median or average or whatever.
I want my model to predict it basing on other parameters. Let's say, I know, my model has a training data like month number, sunny days qty (number of sunny days in that month) and a target value - Y (sales)

```
month   sunny days qty  Y (sales of caps)
8   7   10
9   6   8
```

And now i want to predict Y (sales) in month 12, but I dont know the number of sunny days. I know only the month number.

I want my model to predict sunny days values as well as Y. Is it possible ?

Comment: The term of art you're looking for is *imputation.* Conventionally, imputation is performed first to fill in missing data and then training is done using whatever model you like, but there are a number of variations on this idea: filling in missing observations on the basis of the known observations.

Comment: Re: your edit: Imputation that replaces missing data with the mean is one of the worst ways to do imputation. Better imputation methods exist which use multivariate distributions over the data to predict missing data on the basis of observed data. For example, Amelia II assumes the data are multivariate normal (possibly under a transformation or truncated). The background material here provides some better context: http://r.iq.harvard.edu/docs/amelia/amelia.pdf

Comment: @C11H17N2O2SNa Thanks,, I will check. Sounds like something to start

Comment: @C11H17N2O2SNa With imputation it is not convenient because it is a preprocessing stage as i can i see. So if I saved my trained model and then want to input one row of data, to imputate it with some network I wll need additional library applied to both training and new input data. Not so cool. I was looking for a model that can do both predicting and imputation

Comment: I don't think so. You'll just need to save the imputation model that's used to generate predictions, which is just a mean vector and a covariance matrix. New predictions for missing observations are just posterior draws from a model with that prior. The conjugate properties of the multivariate normal will mean this is just some algebra plus a random number generator.

Comment: @C11H17N2O2SNa Hmm, yes, it makes sense. So, thank you, now it is time to try in practice